# Can I simply replace a tf.nn.conv2d layer with a tf.layer.max_pooling?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to know, how much better is striding compared to pooling.

My current code looks like this

```
w = tf.get_variable('w', [k_h, k_w, output_shape[-1], input_.get_shape()[-1]],
          initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=stddev))
deconv = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(input_, w, output_shape=output_shape, strides=[1, d_h, d_w, 1])
```

Would code underneath more or less equivalent to the code above?

```
tf.layers.max_pooling2d(input_, pooling=2, strides=[1, d_h, d_w, 1], padding='same')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Both are different
- `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` is used for upsampling
- `tf.layers.max_pooling2d` is used for downsampling
- `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` takes a lower dimension image and scales it to a higher dimension image
- `tf.layers.max_pooling2d` takes a higher dimension image and scales it down to a lower dimension image
- You can not replace `tf.nn.conv2d` layer with a `tf.layer.max_pooling` because bot of them are used completely for opposite purpose